# How to select one of two dlls with the same API at run-time?

Tags: vb.net, dll

I have two dlls with the same API accessing different hardware devices (built be me). I want to select one of them at run-time based on which hardware is detected in the computer.

I found that I can use the windows function `LoadLibrary` to load one of the two libraries before I call any function from the DLL, and VB will use the loaded library - but this works only if the file name matches what's in the function `Declare` (or `Dllimport`), i.e. both dll versions have to have the same file name. And this means that the dlls cannot be located in the same directory (such as in the System32 directory).

Can I have two dlls with two different filenames that provide the same API to the VB.NET selectable at run-time?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do conditional imports other than with [**compilation constants**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x435tkbk(v=vs.140).aspx). However you could import both the dlls and make a method which calls either one depending on your condition.

Something like:

```
<DllImport("firstversion.dll", EntryPoint:="GetDevice")> _
Public Shared Function GetDevice_v1(ByVal arg1 As IntPtr, ByVal arg2 As String) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("secondversion.dll", EntryPoint:="GetDevice")> _
Public Shared Function GetDevice_v2(ByVal arg1 As IntPtr, ByVal arg2 As String) As IntPtr
End Function

Public Shared Function GetDevice(ByVal arg1 As IntPtr, ByVal arg2 As String) As IntPtr
    If condition Then
        Return GetDevice_v1(arg1, arg2)
    Else
        Return GetDevice_v2(arg1, arg2)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was trying to avoid using something like that because one of the DLLs is already released and in use and this will require replacing it. I may have no choice...

Comment: @FreddyBen-Zeev : I'm afraid there is no other way, no. But what's wrong with doing it this way? Why would it require you to replace one of the DLLs? -- Your only requirement using this way is to have different names on the DLLs _**or**_ place them in different folders.

Comment: @FreddyBen-Zeev : If my answer didn't solve your problem or you are having some kind of complication please let me know the issue and I might be able to help!